# C++ Build error: expected type-specifier before [Variadic templates] class

Tags: c++14, variadic-templates, stdtuple, index-sequence

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename Obj, typename Method, typename Args, size_t... Ns>
inline void DispatchToMethodImpl(const Obj& obj, Method method, Args&& args,
                                 std::index_sequence<Ns...>) {
  (obj->*method)(std::get<Ns>(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}

template <typename Obj, typename Method, typename Args>
inline void DispatchToMethod(const Obj& obj, Method method, Args&& args) {
  constexpr size_t size = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Args>>::value;
  DispatchToMethodImpl(obj, method, std::forward<Args>(args),
                       std::make_index_sequence<size>());
}

class TaskEventBase {
 public:
  virtual void Run() = 0;
};

template <typename Obj, typename Method, typename Args>
class TaskEvent : public TaskEventBase {
 public:
  TaskEvent(Obj* obj, Method method, Args&& args) {
    obj_ = obj;
    method_ = method;
    args_ = std::forward<Args>(args);
  }

  void Run() override { DispatchToMethod(obj_, method_, args_); }

 private:
  Obj* obj_;
  Method method_;
  Args args_;
};


int main() {
  printf("event loop test start\n");
  struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;

    int Add(int a, int b) {
      printf("res is %d\n", a + b);
      return a + b;
    }
  };

  Foo foo;
  DispatchToMethod(&foo, &Foo::Add, std::make_tuple(1, 2));
  auto e = new TaskEvent(&foo, &Foo::Add, std::make_tuple(1, 2));
  printf("event loop test end\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Try build with:
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++14 -o a  test_template_args.cc

Then I get the following error:

```
test_template_args.cc:70:16: error: expected type-specifier before ‘TaskEvent’                                                                                   
   auto e = new TaskEvent(&foo, &Foo::Add, std::make_tuple(1, 2));
```

I don't understand why DispatchToMethod function template works:

```
DispatchToMethod(&foo, &Foo::Add, std::make_tuple(1, 2));
```

But TaskEvent class template doesn't work:

```
auto e = new TaskEvent(&foo, &Foo::Add, std::make_tuple(1, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C++17 your code works due to [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

Until C++14, the code doesn't work because constructor of `TaskEvent` is non template function, so class template parameters cannot be deduced from the call parameters of `TaskEvent` constructor, contrary to `DispatchToMethod` which is template function - all `Obj`, `Method` and `Args` are deducible from passed arguments of function invocation.

You can explicitly provide template parameters via template arguments list:

```
  auto e = new TaskEvent< Foo,int(Foo::*)(int,int),std::tuple<int,int> >
                    (&foo, &Foo::Add, std::make_tuple(1, 2));
```